# Parse multipart/form-data using cgi.FieldStorage; None keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, multipartform-data

The following piece of code should be able to run in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function

import cgi
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO as IO
except ImportError:
    from io import BytesIO as IO

body = """
--spam
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"; filename=blob
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream

value1
--spam--
"""

parsed = cgi.FieldStorage(
    IO(body.encode('utf-8')),
    headers={'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=spam'},
    environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'})

print([key for key in parsed])
```

In Python 2.7 it runs fine and it outputs `['param1']`. In Python 3.4 however, it outputs `[None]`.

I cannot get `FieldStorage` to get a usable result in Python 3. I suspect something internally changed and I'm now using it wrong. However I can't seem to figure out what. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These changes will make your script work identically in both Python 2.7.x and 3.4.x:

*(I will use these abbreviations for `cgi.FieldStorage()`: Python 2.7.x: **FS27**, Python 3.4.x: **FS34**)*

**1** - While *FS27* handles the newline before the boundary correctly, that is not the case with *FS34* so the solution is to start with your boundary(`spam`) directly.

```python
body = """--spam
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"; filename=blob
Content-type: binary/octet-stream

value1
--spam--
"""
```

**2** - Quoting from ***cgi.py*** [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/cgi.py) (in *FS34's* definition comments):

> Arguments, all optional:
>
> fp          : file pointer; default: sys.stdin.buffer
>               (not used when the request method is GET)
>
> ```
>         Can be :
>         1. a TextIOWrapper object
>         2. an object whose read() and readline() methods return bytes
> ```

The grey part is not present in *FS27* definition, so, most of the differences between *FS27* and *FS34* lie in the handling of *strings(FS27)* and *binary streams(FS34)*.

In this context, *FS34* can easily mess the semantics of the parsed object, unless it is given proper directions on how to handle this correctly. Apparently, the `headers` dictionary entry `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=spam'`
is not enough; you have to supply the message length information.

You can achieve this, *effectively*, by adding a second entry in `headers`:

```
headers={'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=spam;',
'content-length': len(body)}
```

where the *value* for the `content-length` *key* is the  `body` length (including the start/end boundaries).

---

These modifications, combined, lead to the desired result:

```
$ python script.py
['param1']
$ python3 script.py
['param1']
```

---

As *proof-of-concept*, these are the returned `parsed` objects from both *FS27* and *FS34*:

```
...
print(parsed)
...
```

yields:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [FieldStorage('param1', 'blob', 'value1')])
```

for *FS27*, and

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [FieldStorage('param1', 'blob', b'value1')])
```

for *FS34*.

Answer (score 1):

In both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 (not working in Python 3.4 for some reason), the desired output is returned by adding `Content-Length` to the response body:

```
body = """
--spam
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"; filename=blob
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream

value1
--spam--
"""
```